# Qt C++, Eclipse (on Win 7) - project build failed with "unresolved reference to _Unwind_Resume" error

Tags: c++, eclipse, qt, mingw

I've got Windows 7 64-bit and I just installed Qt (open-source, version 2010.04) and integrated it into Eclipse (CDT, version Helios). Everything seemed to went fine, I added paths to both Qt and mingw32 compiler and configured Qt by running configure.exe. The integration with Eclipse works fine too.

However, I've problem with the first simple project. If I create the "Qt Gui Project" and try to immediately build it, the build fails with following errors:

```
mingw32-make: *** [release] Error 2
mingw32-make[1]: *** [release\pokus.exe] Error 1
undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
```

I tried to use also Debug configuration, but the build failed too, with the same errors. However I don't expect Debug configuration to work since I haven't built debug libraries. (in fact I'm not sure how to do this - when I installed Qt few years ago, there was a batch file to do it, but now I couldn't find it.)

As I said before, I have paths to both mingw32 and Qt correctly added to environment path, but don't know what else to check or do... Thanks for all suggestions...

Edit: I found that these errors can be caused by accidentaly using gcc instead of g++. I don't think this is the case, if I look at Project Properties -> C/C++ Make Project -> Environment tab, I can see that value of "QMAKESPEC" variable is "win32-g++", so I hope it means g++ is used for the project.

Comment: Is there a mingw64 compiler since you are now on a 64-bit machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved - problem was with the bad version of MinGW, I had the current version (5.1.6.) installed. I uninstalled it and replaced with version 4.4.0, downloaded from Qt website (http://get.qt.nokia.com/misc/MinGW-gcc440_1.zip) and everything is fine now.

Comment: I wanna ask how do you install mingw from that zip file, do you mean extract all to C:\MINGW\ folder and set path to it?